# Calculating the difference of a column based on the first value of a day and the last value of a day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 columns in SQL, out of which I use only three columns. I need to create a `view` which subtracts the `total_energy_generated_till` value based on the first value of a day and the last value of a day using the column TSTAMP.

How do I achieve the same ? See the image for the table information.

Previously it had the `timestamp` but I converted it into a `Date` data type.

**SQL Table**

[image]

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKlaf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW Your_View_Name
AS
SELECT TSTAMP,Inverter_ID
    ,MAX(TotalEnergyGenerated)-MIN(TotalEnergyGenerated) [total_energy_generated_till]
GROUP BY TSTAMP, Inverter_ID
```

Comment: When I run the query, I get 0 value in all the rows of total_energy_generated_till

Comment: @KrishnamurthyKA, can you give some sample data?

Comment: Please find the **Sample Data** in the picture that I have attached now.

Comment: There are 9 inverters in total which has the same date. For Eg. Inverter_id 1 has 24/08/2017 etc..

Comment: I have attached only for inverter 2.

Answer (score 0):

If TimeStamp is unique you could do something like this:

```
select *
from myTable a
inner join
(
    select 
        MinTimeStamp = min(TimeStamp),
        MaxTimeStamp = max(TimeStamp)
    from myTable
) b
on a.TimeStamp = b.TimeStamp
```

If not, row_number might work too